# Matlab - Symbolic computation for a Fourier transform : no result

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, continuous-fourier, inverse-transform

In Matlab, I would like to compute the inverse Fourier transform symbolically of the following function :

```
cf=1/(1 - beta*t*1i)^N
```

But impossible to get a result with :

```
>> ifourier(cf,t,x)

ans =

fourier(1/(1 - beta*t*1i)^N, t, -x)/(2*pi)
```

Isn't there really no explicit formula for the inverse Fourier transform of this function `cf`

### Edit

I try to use sum and product with log to express in other form the `cf` function :

```
cf=exp(-A(k)*symsum((1-1i*beta*t),k,1,N)
```

with `N=60` and `A=ones(1,N)`.

But when I apply FT, I get :

```
cf=exp(-A(k)*symsum((1-1i*beta*t),k,1,N))
Error using message
In 'symbolic:sym:symsum:InvalidSummationIndex', parameter {0} must be a real scalar.

Error in sym/symsum (line 54)
    error(message('symbolic:sym:symsum:InvalidSummationIndex', char(x)));
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to take the inverse fourier transform of a time domain function?  I'm trying to understand the first function `cf = 1 / (1 - beta*t*1i)^N`.  Which values are constants and which are symbolic?

Comment: @Matt the symbolic variable are `t` (time variable), `beta` and `N` . If the computation cannot be done symbolically with symbolic variable `N`, I can take it as a numerical value equal to `N=60`. Regards

Comment: Your equation appears to some form of exponential which doesn't have periodic properties.  From the `doc ifourier` documentation "If ifourier cannot find an explicit representation of the inverse Fourier transform, then it returns results in terms of the Fourier transform."  In other words `cf / 2pi` is expected.  Normally one uses the inverse fourier transform to go from frequency domain to the time domain.  I could be missing the point of your question though.